# Cancellation Timer in Mysql Connector / J

Tags: mysql

I am facing the below mention problem.

The web application [/helloWorld] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

i am using the mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar which is latest one but it is still giving the problem.

Please help me.

Comment: See this comment to learn more about this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46733027/185565

Answer (score -1):

From the command line window in linux atleast - "ps -A" will give you a list of all your processes - dont type the quotes. You can confirm that it is in that list or just type "ps -A | grep MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer. This will return you a process ID. Then type kill ##### (whatever your process id is that you want to kill). Hope that helps

Comment: this is the manual intervention of one to find process id and then kill it. And this will always give error in my log file and i don't want it to be there.