# What is WebappClassLoaderBase error about and how to solve this?

Tags: linux, tomcat, centos, webserver

I have Apache Web Server and running some projects on it. Unfortunately I am getting this error and tried by restarting httpd service but did not get any solution. **Please help me suggesting some solution.**

```
07-Dec-2021 23:31:27.331 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [PTDS] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
07-Dec-2021 23:31:27.337 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [PTDS] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
07-Dec-2021 23:31:27.366 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-2555"]
07-Dec-2021 23:31:27.366 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-2555"]
07-Dec-2021 23:31:27.367 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
07-Dec-2021 23:31:27.367 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer failed to Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907018/mysql-statement-cancellation-timer-failed-to-stop)

Comment: Is it related MySql? No, I think the link which you have given is not related to what I am looking for.